# apply_filters() and call_user_func() to define and call a function outside a class

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions

Hi Please see the following code of my class

```
class MyClass {
     function __construct() {
        $this->autoload_function();
     }
     
     function autoload_function(){
        $my_array=array("test1");
        foreach ( $my_array as $my_function ){
         call_user_func($my_function);
        }
     }
     
     function test1(){
        echo 'hii- test1';
     }
}

$var = new MyClass();
```

Here I have to add other values to **$my_array** and then I have to define other function outside this class . I have to do this via add_filter. So I modified the code please see below

**my-class.php**

```
class MyClass {
     function __construct() {
        $this->autoload_function();
     }
     
     function autoload_function(){
        $my_array=array("test1");

        apply_filters('modify_array', $my_array);

        foreach ( $my_array as $my_function ){
         call_user_func($my_function);
        }
     }
     
     function test1(){
        echo 'hii- test1';
     }
}

$var = new MyClass();
```

**my-newpage.php**

```
add_filter ('modify_array', 'modify_array_function', 0);


function modify_array_function($my_array){
 array_push($my_array, 'test2')
}

function test2(){
 echo 'hii- test2';
}
```

Here i can see that new value is added to array but i am not sure about where i can write my new function i am getting following error

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
> class **'MyClass' does not have a method**
> **'test2'**

I want to define  test2() inside my-newpage.php and I am ready to add more action or filter inside my-class.php

I setup everything in a proper way that's why **add_filter ('modify_array', 'modify_array_function', 0);** is working .

Please help.

Comment: If you want to modify a value then you should be using `apply_filters`, not `add_action`: `$my_array = apply_filters( 'modify_array', $my_array );`. This isn't the cause of your problem though.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thank you for the suggestion. You are right, modified it .

Comment: actually i mad it using add_action because i think that i can define the function inside add action function ie  function modify_array_function($my_array){  funtion test2(){ echo 'hii- test2'; } array_push($my_array, 'test2') } but that also not working